# Alchemy Resource Error

Tags: web8, a4t

I'm seeing this error message when testing my plugin in SDL Web 8.

> The resource object with key 'None' was not found.

It previously worked in earlier versions of SDL Tridion.

Answer (score 9):

SDL has changed the namespace of their resource strings so something like :

`<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, None %>`

Will not work in Web8.

It's recommended to create your own resource strings in your Alchemy project rather than piggy back on SDL's.

Answer (score 1):

As Josh says, the namespace for the CME resource strings has been updated for Web 8.

Rather than `Tridion.Web.UI.Strings`, these are now in the  `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings` namespace.

So, for example, when upgrading the 'Publish from Publish Queue' extension, I have updated the GUI Extension config file to reference the labels in the following manner, and the labels (e.g. Publish, Unpublish, etc.) now display correctly:

```
<cmenu:ContextMenuItem id="cm_pq_publish" command="PqPublish" name="{Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, Publish}" />
```

These strings appear to be defined in the following file:
**%Tridion_Home%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\App_GlobalResources\Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings.resx**