# How to install "Republish" extension

Tags: web8, gui-extensions

I downloaded "Republish" from SDL App Store, but I can't find how to install it.

http://appstore.sdl.com/app/republish/756/

Is this installed as GUI Extension?

If it's a GUI Extension, how are following files used?

- `Alchemy.Plugins.Republish.dll`
- `a4t.xml`
- `icon.png`

Or is only an "assets" folder used?

**Update:**

After installed UI extension version to Web 8.1, context menus looks like this image. 
Is this adapted to Web 8.1?

[image]

Regards,

Comment: This missing text is due to a namespace change in the anguila framework. Please see: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/17255/71

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the description, it's actually an [Alchemy](http://www.alchemywebstore.com) plugin. So first you need to make sure you [have Alchemy installed](http://www.alchemywebstore.com/downloads) on your CME server.

Once you do, you don't actually get much benefit from downloading it from the SDL App Store -- you might as well click the *Install* button for the plugin [in the Alchemy Web Store](http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Republish).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a UI extension version available of it here: http://appstore.sdl.com/app/publish-from-publishing-queue-extension/632/, but I have to first tell you that we are currently still busy with the migration of all extensions from SDL Tridion World to the new SDL Appstore (nice that you found it already there ;o).

The installation instructions of the UI extension (which was last updated for 2013, so for Web 8 you will need to make some modifications by the way) are uploaded on the appstore, but they are not visible yet (a technical issue that is being worked on). So if you want to use the UI extension, then follow the installation instructions here http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/publishfrompublishingqueue.aspx and for making the required changes, you can get the complete source code of it here: https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Publish%20from%20Publishing%20Queue/trunk

### update

As mentioned the appstore is not completely live yet (I'll notify the team about the download issue), but more importantly, the extension was last updated for 2013, and never properly tested on Web 8.

I just did a quick push of a few changes to https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Publish%20from%20Publishing%20Queue/trunk which might be working better for Web 8 (not trying to reuse the icons from the CME but adding its own). I didn't test it, so if you find more issues, let me know and we can maybe look at solving it together.

Comment: I downloaded UI extension version from SDL Tridion World (I couldn't download it from SDL App Store because of an error), but after installed it to Web 8.1, context menu is not correct(see an image added to my question). Is this adapted to Web 8.1?

Comment: @HirokazuShikata I updated my answer, it was last released for 2013, never properly tested for Web 8, which is why you found what you found indeed.

Comment: I installed new version, and text "Publish" and "UnPublished" appear on context menu(but icons still don't appear). Basic operations like publishing or unpublishing components and pages are OK on Web 8.1.1.